# How to get DataGridView cell value in messagebox?

Tags: c#, datagridview, messagebox

How can I get DataGridView cell value to be written in the MessageBox in C#?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [DataGridViewCell.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) Property to retrieve the value stored in a particular cell.

So to retrieve the value of the 'first' selected Cell and display in a MessageBox, you can:

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());
```

The above probably isn't exactly what you need to do.  If you provide more details we can provide better help.

Comment: thanks! but its enough, what you told me, solved my problem :)

Comment: MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value?.ToString());

Answer (score 28):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
MessageBox.Show(" Value at 0,0" + DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value );
```

Answer (score 5):

```
      try
        {

            for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rows++)
            {

                for (int col = 0; col < dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells.Count; col++)
                {
                    s1 = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    label20.Text = s1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("try again"+ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value));
    }
```

a bit late but hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

I added this to the Button of a datagrid to get the values of the cells in the row that the user is clicking:

---

```
string DGCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[X].Value.ToString();
```

where X is the cell you want to check. Datagrid column count starts at 1 not 0 in my case. Not sure if it is default of a datagrid or because I am using SQL to populate the info.

Answer (score 2):

> Sum all cells

```
        double X=0;
        if (datagrid.Rows.Count-1 > 0)
        {
           for(int i = 0; i < datagrid.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {
               for(int j = 0; j < datagrid.Rows.Count-1; j++)
               {
                  X+=Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
               }
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
           int rowIndex = e.RowIndex; // Get the order of the current row 
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];//Store the value of the current row in a variable
            MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[rowIndex].Value.ToString());//show message for current row
    }
```

Comment: Hi @سعد الضبي Could you add some commentary around this code block?