# How to add Datagridview values in mongodb collection?

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio, datagridview, bson

I am using MongoDB in my windows form project, in this project I added `Datagridview`. I want to add that `Datagridview` values in my MongoDM using bson. Please, tell me how to do this.i got error in for loop in bson.

```
                BsonDocument invoice = new BsonDocument()
                .Add("invoice", "invoice")
                .Add("name", textBox21.Text + " " + textBox22.Text + " " + textBox23.Text)
                .Add("at_post", textBox24.Text)
                .Add("taluka", textBox25.Text)
                .Add("district", textBox26.Text)
                .Add("state", textBox27.Text)
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                { 
                .Add("Discription", )
                 }
                .Add("Quantity", textBox28.Text)
                .Add("rate", textBox24.Text)
                .Add("total_advance", textBox13.Text)
                .Add("invoice_num", textBox11.Text)
                .Add("Total",textBox1.Text)
                .Add("datetime",this.dateTimePicker1.Text)
                .Add("fname",textBox21.Text)
                .Add("mname", textBox22.Text)
                .Add("lname", textBox23.Text);

                colle.Insert(invoice);here
```

Comment: Hi, to begin with I don't get the ".Add("Discription", )" that "per se" wont build..

Comment: Dsicription is key and i want to add my datagrid cells value in it.

Comment: then this post is probably duplicated with [How to get DataGridView cell value in messagebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571963/how-to-get-datagridview-cell-value-in-messagebox)