# Getting all cell data from a specific column in a Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Let's say the datagridview has 3 columns.
The Datagridview is filled with data form a SQL database.
Now i want the data of the column 'age' and write it to a list so i can use the data late but i only want the INTs. Can some please help me? a code example would be lovely.

```
|---------|----------|----------|
|    id   |   name   |   age    |
|---------|----------|----------|
|    1    |   john   |   20     |
|---------|----------|----------| 
|    2    |   jane   |   21     |
|---------|----------|----------|
|    3    |   jack   |   22     |
|---------|----------|----------|
```

Comment: Here is similar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571963/how-to-get-datagridview-cell-value-in-messagebox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get DataGridView cell value in messagebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571963/how-to-get-datagridview-cell-value-in-messagebox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pretty simple.

```
For Each row As DataRow In YourDataGridView.Rows
  Dim age = CInt(row("age"))
Next
```

Then you can do whatever you want with age variable inside that loop.
Or you can use LINQ to get list of ages.

```
Dim allAges = (From row As DataGridViewRow
               In YourDataGridView.Rows
               Select DirectCast(row.Cells("age").Value, Integer)).ToList()
```

Comment: I like your LINQ solution can you give me a tip how i can filter DBnull's out?

Comment: Insert Where Not IsDBNull(row.Cells("age").Value) between In and Select.