# C# User selecting a cell in a DataGridView doesn't trigger the SelectionChanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on a Windows Form that's got two DataGrids.

I'm currently trying to make it so that when one cell is selected in DataGridView1, something else is being displayed in DataGridView2.

The problem is that when I run my app, selecting any of the cells doesn't do anything at all.

I've tried using

```
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("The selected cell has changed!");
};
```

to check and see if the event is registering, and nothing happened.

The SelectionMode for the DataGridView is set to CellSelect.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Examples:-[Check This Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657137/datagridview-full-row-selection-but-get-single-cell-value)

```
     private void datagridview1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (datagridview1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
         {
             int selectedrowindex = datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

             DataGridViewRow selectedRow = datagridview1.Rows[selectedrowindex];  

              string a = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["you have to mention you cell  corresponding column name"].Value);           


         }
     }
```

Use this And Take [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571963/how-to-get-datagridview-cell-value-in-messagebox)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Another

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());
```

Check this property Also `DataGridView1.FullRowSelect = true`

Comment: I tried both of these and switching it to FullRowSelect and it still won't register me clicking or selecting any of the cells or rows despite them being highlighted as selected :(

Comment: Then Add Full Code Please

Comment: If you want whole new then refer this tutorial https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/edit-and-update-record-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Another tutorial https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/insert-update-and-delete-record-in-datagridview-C-Sharp/

Comment: private void grdAdreseClienti_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("It works!");} this is the exact code I'm using, minus  the formatting. Selecting a cell does not do anything at all :(