# context.Instance.[GetType]().GetField("xxx") returns null value in UserControl

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have a Windows Forms usercontrol containing a datagridview control named "DGV"
However, the code

```
Dim field = context.Instance.[GetType]().
    GetField("DGV", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
```

returns null. When I inspect context.Instance.Name it returns, correctly, the name of my usercontrol. I've tried modifiers of Private and Friend on "DGV" with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you make the DGV public and `context.Instance` is typed as your specific UserControl, then you can simply access it with `context.Instance.DGV`.

Comment: Sadly, no - this returns the DGV itself rather than the field data

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what `Instance` is and what you exactly want to return with `GetField`. If the class of `Instance` has a field named `DGV`, then the `GetField` version and my version will both return this field. Note: `GetField` does return a class field, not a field (a Cell) in a DataGridView. Maybe this this what you want: [How to get DataGridView cell value in messagebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5571963/880990).